# Bash Shell Script - Difficulty joining two different Finds into 1 or simply comparing the result

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm trying to write a program that allows me to do a find on a directory then run a find on another directory and if the name of the files are the same but written in different cases and so on, output for me the result of these files.

However, for now, I am having difficulty joining these two finds and running an "if" on them.

So far:

```
if ($(find teste1) != (find teste2)) then
echo "They are different"
else
echo "They are the same"
fi
```

I know this is miles away from what I said in the beginning but if I can't even run this simple "IF" command on my finds, I'm going to have a difficult time running the rest.

So, what exactly is wrong with my syntax above? And in case you haven't noticed, I am a total newbie on Shell Script, I started only yesterday and I've been trying to do some research on "joining two different FIND" but I'm having some difficulty on that.

Can anyone help me out? Or point me towards a good direction for me to keep practicing and get where I want?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Thank you! :) Gonna go from there for the rest of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, try this:

```
if [ "$(find teste1 -printf %P)" != "$(find teste2 -printf %P)" ]
then
  echo "They are different"
else
  echo "They are the same"
fi
```

Changes made:

1. You need to use brackets `[...]` or double brackets `[[...]]` for an equality test.
2. You are looking to compare the output of both find commands, so both should be in commands substitution brackets `$(...)` and quoted.
3. The `then` that follows `if` must be on a new line or separated by a semicolon (although there does not need to be a newline between `then` and the next command).
4. The output of `find` is normally prepended by the directory you have specified to search in, thus the output will always be different for two different directories. This is why I have added `-printf %P`, below is man page section for the `%P` part:

> %P     File's name with the name of the command line argument under which it was found removed.

Comment: Much fun in case that `find` produces a large output.  Will be extremely slow then and will even fail if the output is too large to handle for the shell.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Graeme, I guess it's like GreenAsJade said, I have to dig more on the "how to bash" before the rest :)

Comment: +1 for using `%P` to ignore argument path in comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
diff <(find test1) <(find test2)
```

for comparing the *output* of subshells, passed as pseudo files.

For a simple comparing for equality, use `cmp` of course:

```
if cmp -s <(find test1) <(find test2)
then
  echo "equal"
else
  echo "different"
fi
```

This way a difference in the beginning leads to an early abortion of the subshells (due to broken pipes) and thus does not compute unnecessary stuff.

Comment: You will need to use `-printf %P` with `find` or otherwise trim the directory from the start of each line of output for this to work or else you will never get "equal".

Comment: Of course.  In practice the commands will be sth like this:  `diff <(cd /path/to/test1; find .) <(cd /path/tp/test2; find .)`  But that applies to the question itself here, and consequently to all answers referring it.  But using `%P` to achieve this also is a nice way of putting it.  You'll get my +1 for this :)

Comment: Actually `cd` is probably a better idea, it will be more portable.